# Spring wont read .env

Tags: application.properties, .env

My app wont get data from .env file. I have set

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
```

in my application.properties. If i change this, it will immediately say file does not exist. So it sees the file (probably) but wont acces any data in it (returning null).

I tried implement dependency:

```
implementation 'io.github.cdimascio:java-dotenv:5.2.2'
```

I tried get values with:

```
@Value("${JWT_SECRET_KEY}")
  private String jwtSecret;
```

and

```
System.getenv();
```

I tried remove .env from gitignore
I tried different imports like:

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
spring.config.import=file:.env[.properties]
```

in application.properties
I tried add: JWT_SECRET_KEY=${JWT_SECRET_KEY} directly in application.properties.
I tried @ComponentScan with path annotation
I tried get values with import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
I tried use envFile plugin in Intellij

Im working in Intellij, using corretto-17, SpringBoot, Gradle. .env is in root dir of a project.

Comment: What happens if you set `spring.config.import=.env`?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateExceptio: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader.
Unable to load config data from '.env'

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please go ahead and accept it. If it didn't solve your problem, do post a comment and let me know what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Spring only can read `.properties` and YAML files, which it determines based on the file extension. To read random files that are in properties format, you can create a custom property source as shown below.

Create a class that implements the `EnvironmentPostProcessor` interface and override the `postProcessEnvironment()` method. In this method, you can add the custom `PropertySource` to the `Environment` object.

```
public class CustomPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        PropertySource<?> customPropertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("env", properties);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(customPropertySource);
    }
}
```

The `properties` is a Java `Properties` object that you can create using Spring `Resource` injection.

```
@Value("classpath:.env")
private Resource resource;
```

How to turn a `Resource` into `Properties` is a fairly trivial exercise that I'll leave to you.